# 802.11 Management Frame element decoding

Tags: ieee-802.11

An IEEE 802.11 Management Frame can contain multiple "Element" fields, which are effectively TLVs (a Type, a Length, and a Value).

Other than Type 211 for "Vendor Specific", are there any Element IDs that may occur more than once within a packet?   I can't find any specific text within 802.11-2016 that says either way.

(The underlying reason for the question is that I need to know whether it's practical to store decoded elements keyed by ID within my code.  If IDs can be repeated then this would prevent that)